# browserify api use to file without gulp to trigger callback on success

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

Does anyone know of a way of triggering a callback once browserify has written the output to disk?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var b = browserify({standalone: 'MyAppModules'});
b.add('./browserifyMain.js');
b.bundle().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/js/bundle2.js'));
```

This works, but i need to run an rsync only when the bundle is built.

I tried adding an 'on' event listener based on this post: [How to use the new Browserify API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509428/how-to-use-the-new-browserify-api)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var b = browserify({standalone: 'MyAppModules'});
b.add('./browserifyMain.js');
b.bundle().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/js/bundle.js')).on('end', function(){
    console.log( 'finished writing the browserify file' );
});
```

But the log is never returned so i am assuming this doesn't work either :/

Also, tried, but did not work either:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var bundleFs = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/js/bundle.js');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var b = browserify({standalone: 'MyAppModules'});
b.add('./browserifyMain.js');
b.bundle().pipe( bundleFs )
bundleFs.on('end', function(){
    console.log( 'finished writing the browserify file' );
});
return;
```

(all of the above do write the file correctly though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.beingyesterday.com/write-browserify-to-file-using-the-api/

I found the answer and added to my blog... listen out for the "finish" event. This was used in the browserify bundle in quilk for easier control with simple json files https://johnc1984.github.io/quilk/Modules_baked_in/browserify_bundle.html

```
var fs = require('fs');
var browserify = require('browserify');

module.exports = function( callback ) {

    callback = callback || function(){};

    // Create a write stream for the pipe to output to
    var bundleFs = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/browserify/bundle.js');

    var b = browserify({standalone: 'nodeModules'});
    b.add('./browserifyMain.js');
    b.bundle().pipe(bundleFs);

    //now listen out for the finish event to know when things have finished 
    bundleFs.on('finish', function () {
        console.log('finished writing the browserify file');
        return callback();
    });
};
```